# How do I view the contents of a SELinux policy package

Tags: centos, selinux, centos6

As the title says, how do I view the contents of a SELinux policy package? The resulting files end with .pp. I'm running on centos 6, but I guess it's the same way on "all" distros.

For example

```
    cp /usr/share/selinux/targeted/cobbler.pp.bz2 ~
    bunzip2 cobbler.pp.bz2 
    MAGIC_SELINUX_CMD cobbler.pp
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A SELinux policy module is built by following steps:

1. generate a set of policy rules: `audit2allow`
2. compile: `checkmodule`
3. build: `semodule_package`

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Assuming that I have a `postgreylocal.te` file with belows content:

```
module postgreylocal 1.0;
require {
        type postfix_smtpd_t;
        type postfix_spool_t;
        type initrc_t;
        class sock_file write;
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}
#============= postfix_smtpd_t ==============
allow postfix_smtpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
allow postfix_smtpd_t postfix_spool_t:sock_file write;
```

`postgreylocal.pp` policy module will be created with:

```
# checkmodule -M -m -o postgreylocal.mod postgreylocal.te
# semodule_package -m postgreylocal.mod -o postgreylocal.pp
```

To unpack this policy module, you need a tool which is called [semodule_unpackage](http://userspace.selinuxproject.org/trac/browser/policycoreutils/semodule_package/semodule_unpackage.c) to extract the `.mod` file and then use [`dismod`](http://userspace.selinuxproject.org/trac/browser/checkpolicy/test/dismod.c) to disassemble the binary module to textual representation.

On my Gentoo, the following packages need to be installed:

```
[I] sys-apps/policycoreutils
     Available versions:  [M]2.0.82 [M](~)2.0.82-r1 [M](~)2.0.85 [M](~)2.1.0 {M}(~)2.1.0-r1
     Installed versions:  2.1.0-r1(05:12:27 PM 10/14/2011)
     Homepage:            http://userspace.selinuxproject.org
     Description:         SELinux core utilities

[I] sys-apps/checkpolicy
     Available versions:  [M]2.0.21 [M](~)2.0.23 {M}(~)2.1.0 {debug}
     Installed versions:  2.1.0(01:27:53 PM 10/14/2011)(-debug)
     Homepage:            http://userspace.selinuxproject.org
     Description:         SELinux policy compiler

[I] sys-libs/libsepol
     Available versions:  [M]2.0.41!t [M](~)2.0.42!t {M}(~)2.1.0!t
     Installed versions:  2.1.0!t(01:25:43 PM 10/14/2011)
     Homepage:            http://userspace.selinuxproject.org
     Description:         SELinux binary policy representation library
```

Firstly, extract the module from `.pp` file:

```
# semodule_unpackage postgreylocal.pp postgreylocal.mod
```

and secondly, disassemble with `dismod`:

```
# cd checkpolicy-2.1.0/test/
# ls
dismod.c  dispol.c  Makefile
# make
cc -g -Wall -O2 -pipe -I/usr/include   -c -o dispol.o dispol.c
dispol.c: In function ‘main’:
dispol.c:438:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
dispol.c:465:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
dispol.c:476:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
dispol.c:500:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
cc   dispol.o  -lfl -lsepol -lselinux /usr/lib/libsepol.a -L/usr/lib -o dispol
cc -g -Wall -O2 -pipe -I/usr/include   -c -o dismod.o dismod.c
dismod.c: In function ‘main’:
dismod.c:913:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
dismod.c:982:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
dismod.c: In function ‘link_module’:
dismod.c:787:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
cc   dismod.o  -lfl -lsepol -lselinux /usr/lib/libsepol.a -L/usr/lib -o dismod
# ls
dismod  dismod.c  dismod.o  dispol  dispol.c  dispol.o  Makefile
```

---

```
./dismod postgreylocal.pp
Reading policy...
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security:  0 users, 1 roles, 3 types, 0 bools
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security: 0 sens, 0 cats
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security:  2 classes, 0 rules, 0 cond rules
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security:  0 users, 1 roles, 3 types, 0 bools
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security: 0 sens, 0 cats
libsepol.policydb_index_others: security:  2 classes, 0 rules, 0 cond rules
Binary policy module file loaded.
Module name: postgreylocal
Module version: 1.0


Select a command:
1)  display unconditional AVTAB
2)  display conditional AVTAB
3)  display users
4)  display bools
5)  display roles
6)  display types, attributes, and aliases
7)  display role transitions
8)  display role allows
9)  Display policycon
0)  Display initial SIDs

a)  Display avrule requirements
b)  Display avrule declarations
c)  Display policy capabilities
l)  Link in a module
u)  Display the unknown handling setting
F)  Display filename_trans rules

f)  set output file
m)  display menu
q)  quit
```

---

```
Command ('m' for menu):  1
unconditional avtab:
--- begin avrule block ---
decl 1:
  allow [postfix_smtpd_t] [initrc_t] : [unix_stream_socket] { connectto };
  allow [postfix_smtpd_t] [postfix_spool_t] : [sock_file] { write };

Command ('m' for menu):  a
avrule block requirements:
--- begin avrule block ---
decl 1:
commons: <empty>
classes: sock_file{  write } unix_stream_socket{  connectto }
roles  : <empty>
types  : postfix_smtpd_t postfix_spool_t initrc_t
users  : <empty>
bools  : <empty>
levels : <empty>
cats   : <empty>

Command ('m' for menu):
```

Comment: fyi, on Fedora (17) it is `sedismod`. It is already available along with `checkpolicy` and `semodule_unpack` with the default installation. Btw, via `semodule_unpackage foo.pp foo.mod foo.fc` you can also extract the filecontexts file.

Comment: The links in this post are 404.  Could you update them?  I need to install *semodule_unpackage* and *dismod* for my box. Thanks!

Comment: `dismod` can be found in the SELinux source code

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting a problem like `wrong magic number for module package:  expected 0xf97cff8f, got 0x39685a42`?

.pp files are stored internally in bzip2 format, so you'll need to do `bzip2 -cdk policyfile.pp > policyfile.pp.out`
BEFORE
`semodule_unpackage policyfile.pp.out policyfile.mod`.

Comment: Compiled policy files are not compressed with BZip2 : `bzip2: policy.30 is not a bzip2 file.`

Comment: Installed policy files are compressed as bzip2, as `file` will attest. Even though the suffix is not changed ...