# How do I configure SELinux on Centos 6 for cobbler?

Tags: centos, selinux, centos6, cobbler

I have installed and configured Cobbler on my centos 6 "installation server". From what I think I did all the configurations I'm supposed to. The installation was performed with my own customized python script that can be found [here](https://github.com/systemconsole/syco/blob/master/bin/public/installCobbler.py). But basically it's imports, repo add, profile add, reposync and other standard commands.

During the installation SELinux was in permissive mode, and added lots of stuff to the /var/log/audit/audit.log.

After the installation I did execute the following to generate SELinux rules.

```
    cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m sycocobbler
```

Which gave me.

```
    module sycocobbler 1.0;

    require {
      type semanage_store_t;
      type syslogd_t;
      type sysfs_t;
      type var_lock_t;
      type rpm_var_cache_t;
      type httpd_sys_content_t;
      type proc_net_t;
      type file_context_t;
      type semanage_read_lock_t;
      type lib_t;
      type sysctl_modprobe_t;
      type security_t;
      type cobblerd_t;
      type modules_conf_t;
      type rpm_var_lib_t;
      type tftpdir_rw_t;
      type modules_dep_t;
      type devlog_t;
      type sysctl_kernel_t;
      type modules_object_t;
      type default_context_t;
      class rawip_socket { getopt create };
      class capability { net_admin net_raw fsetid sys_ptrace };
      class file { rename setattr read lock create write getattr unlink open };
      class netlink_audit_socket create;
      class sock_file { write getattr };
      class lnk_file { read create getattr };
      class unix_dgram_socket { create connect sendto };
      class dir { rename search setattr read create write getattr rmdir remove_name open add_name };
    }

    #============= cobblerd_t ==============
    allow cobblerd_t default_context_t:dir search;
    allow cobblerd_t devlog_t:sock_file { write getattr };
    allow cobblerd_t file_context_t:dir search;
    #!!!! The source type 'cobblerd_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
    # cobbler_var_lib_t, tftpdir_rw_t, cobbler_cache_t, httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t, public_content_rw_t

    allow cobblerd_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir { rename write rmdir setattr remove_name create add_name };
    allow cobblerd_t httpd_sys_content_t:file { write rename create unlink setattr };
    #!!!! The source type 'cobblerd_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
    # var_lib_t, var_log_t, named_zone_t, var_t, cobbler_var_lib_t, tftpdir_rw_t, etc_t, cobbler_cache_t, httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t, public_content_rw_t, root_t

    allow cobblerd_t lib_t:dir { write remove_name add_name };
    allow cobblerd_t lib_t:file { write create unlink };
    allow cobblerd_t modules_conf_t:dir { read search open };
    allow cobblerd_t modules_conf_t:file { read getattr open };
    allow cobblerd_t modules_dep_t:file { read getattr open };
    allow cobblerd_t modules_object_t:dir search;
    allow cobblerd_t modules_object_t:file { read open };
    allow cobblerd_t proc_net_t:file { read getattr open };
    #!!!! The source type 'cobblerd_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
    # cobbler_var_lib_t, tftpdir_rw_t, cobbler_cache_t, httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t, public_content_rw_t

    allow cobblerd_t rpm_var_cache_t:dir { search read create write getattr remove_name open add_name };
    allow cobblerd_t rpm_var_cache_t:file { rename create unlink open setattr };
    #!!!! The source type 'cobblerd_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
    # var_lib_t, var_log_t, named_zone_t, cobbler_var_log_t, var_t, cobbler_var_lib_t, tftpdir_rw_t, etc_t, cobbler_cache_t, httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t, public_content_rw_t, root_t

    allow cobblerd_t rpm_var_lib_t:dir { write search getattr };
    allow cobblerd_t rpm_var_lib_t:file open;
    allow cobblerd_t security_t:dir read;
    allow cobblerd_t self:capability { net_admin net_raw fsetid sys_ptrace };
    allow cobblerd_t self:netlink_audit_socket create;
    allow cobblerd_t self:rawip_socket { getopt create };
    allow cobblerd_t self:unix_dgram_socket { create connect };
    allow cobblerd_t semanage_read_lock_t:file { read lock open };
    #!!!! The source type 'cobblerd_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
    # var_lib_t, var_log_t, named_zone_t, var_t, cobbler_var_lib_t, tftpdir_rw_t, etc_t, cobbler_cache_t, httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t, public_content_rw_t, root_t

    allow cobblerd_t semanage_store_t:dir { read write search };
    allow cobblerd_t semanage_store_t:file { read getattr open };
    allow cobblerd_t sysctl_kernel_t:dir search;
    allow cobblerd_t sysctl_modprobe_t:file read;
    allow cobblerd_t sysfs_t:dir { search getattr };
    allow cobblerd_t sysfs_t:file { read getattr open };
    allow cobblerd_t syslogd_t:unix_dgram_socket sendto;
    allow cobblerd_t tftpdir_rw_t:lnk_file { read create getattr };
    allow cobblerd_t var_lock_t:dir search;
    allow cobblerd_t var_lock_t:file getattr;
```

Am I supposed to add this to the SELinux policy? Or is it any official policy that I have missed? Is the above correct, my current SELinux skills are not good enough determine that.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package/321422#321422) answer, redirect the SELinux rules to a file which is called `cobbler.te`.

You can compile it with:

```
# checkmodule -M -m -o cobbler.mod cobbler.te
```

then create module package and install by executing:

```
# semodule_package -m cobbler.mod -o cobbler.pp 
# semodule -i cobbler.pp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm aware of that part. What I don't know is if the policy itself is valid? Or does it give cobbler access to too many things, and making the box "unsecure"?

Comment: No need to worry because this policy is generated from the issues which were logged at `audit.log` when setting SELinux to `Permissive` mode.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will run with that policy until either the Cobbler team fixes their policy or I get some time to really learn the SELinux stuff =)