# SELinux: Letting Apache talk to MySQL on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, centos, selinux

So I have chrooted MySQL into /opt/chroot/mysql, and everything runs fine. Apache is configured normally, and also runs fine.

I created a small PHP script which connects to the MySQL Daemon, and configured PHP so that the default socket used is the chrooted one. When SELinux is disabled, the script is able to connect fine. However, when SELinux is enabled, the script fails to connect (with error number 13), and the audit log tells me that SELinux denied the request.

Every tutorial I've found that deals with this problem tells me to disable SELinux. This is not what I want to do, so please don't suggest it! I want a solution that works whilst SELinux is enabled...I assume one must exist...

I'd guess that I probably have to change the SELinux contexts for the mysql files, but I'm not sure what to change them into to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

> type=AVC msg=audit(1318863312.959:435): avc: denied { connectto } for
>   pid=12472 comm="httpd"
>   path="/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
>   scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>   tclass=unix_stream_socket

You can build the custom SELinux policy module by following steps:

```
# grep httpd_t audit.log | audit2allow -m httpd > httpd.te
# checkmodule -M -m -o httpd.mod httpd.te
# semodule_package -m httpd.mod -o httpd.pp 
# semodule -i httpd.pp
```

Refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package) topic for more details.

---

**UPDATE**

1. Run `semanage` command to add a context mapping for `/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql/`:

   ```
   # semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql(/.*)?"
   ```
2. And use `restorecon` command to apply this context mapping:

   ```
   # restorecon -Rv /opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql
   ```

---

If you are connecting via TCP/IP, try this:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: Alas, I'm connecting to a local socket. You'd think the solution should be easier for local sockets...

Comment: There's a more specific sebool for this, actually:

`# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Comment: Well I ran the context mapping command, and it changed all the contexts fine. I also ran both the setsebool commands, and they ran fine too.

The PHP page still displays the error: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)", even when I restarted both MySQL and Apache.

Comment: Also, the audit log reports this error: `type=AVC msg=audit(1318863312.959:435): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=12472 comm="httpd" path="/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket`

Comment: Change the above commands to corresponding datadir `/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql/` and try again.

Comment: Thanks, your second update (with custom SE policy) worked perfectly!

Comment: +1. Was able to use the custom SELinux policy package build steps to solve my problem @ http://serverfault.com/questions/433726/selinux-allow-multiple-services-access-to-same-home-dir

Comment: [mysql selinux](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql) would indicate that `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql(/.*)?" &&  restorecon -Rv /opt/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql` would a simpler approach.