# how do i inspect the contents of an selinux module?

Tags: selinux

I would like to view the [textual] contents of an selinux module, say for instance, `/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/udev.pp`.

I tried sedismod, but I get the following error on Fedora 21:

```
% sudo sedismod /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/udev.pp
Reading policy...
libsepol.policydb_read: policydb magic number 0x39685a42 does not match expected magic number 0xf97cff8c or 0xf97cff8d
sedismod:  error(s) encountered while loading policy
```

I'd like to understand that error - searching for an explanation has not born fruit yet.

p.s. I see [How do I view the contents of a SELinux policy package](https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package), but it is somewhat stale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the contents of a SELinux policy package](https://serverfault.com/questions/321301/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-selinux-policy-package)

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer the question:
sedismod needs the bunzipped version of the file, apperently. I ran into the same problem, but after using bunzip2 on the file, sedis

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation is welcome. Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability.  Thanks in advance.